# Downlaod the inner dependecies which are defined inside *.js using require statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am downloading few javascript files from online[consider here 10 files A.js, B.js, C.js..........Etc]..

Example:In each *.js I have again some 100 dependencies javascript files.
EX. A.js[require('a'), require('b'), require('c')......]
    B.js[require('e'), require('f'), require('d')......]

Here my doubt is, I can download all the javascript files and store it in some folder, by uisnig any of the server side programming languages such as Node.js or Java. This can be done easily.

**But the other dependencies which are defined in each A.js, B.js with require statements is not able to download. So my inner dependencies for each *.js is missiing.
Please provide any possible approach for all the inner dependencies to download and store in the path.**

Comment: It's the recommended way to use npm/bower to install node.js/web js required 3rd party packages, 'coz they can resolve all the further dependencies.

Comment: FYI I don't want use the npm/bower or anyother package manager, Could you please any alternate solutuion

Comment: No, I don't have.